# Passing <cfselect> hard coded values into a session scope

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfform

I have a cfform with multiple fields and I'm using an onpage post method to post information gathered from the user's entries into a session to pass onto each page of the registration process.

What I cannot figure out for the life of me and this is probably something simple is that if I have hard coded options for a  how can I pass what is selected into the session? I can get a session.house.main.form.saletype is undefined error when trying to display the value selected on the next page. All my other form fields show up fine.

I removed all the other form fields to make it easier to check my code:

```
    <cfif not structKeyExists(session.house, "main")>
        <cfset session.house.main= {saletype="",
                                    name=""}>
    </cfif>

    <cfparam name="form.saletype" default="#session.house.main.saletype#">
    <cfparam name="form.name" default="#session.house.main.name#">

    <cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
            <cfset session.house.main = {saletype=form.saletype,
                                         name=form.name}>
    <cflocation url="page2.cfm" addtoken="false" />
    </cfif>

    <cfform method="post">
    <cfselect name="saletype" size="1">
                        <option value="Lease" selected>Lease</option>
                        <option value="Rent Now">Rent Now</option>
                    </cfselect><br />
   <cfinput type="text" name="name" id="name" value="#form.name#" required="yes" message="Please enter your name"><br />
        <cfinput type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save"><br />
        </cfform>
```

Edit: Fixed cfselect name. How would I set the form.saletype into the cfselect with two hardcoded options?

Comment: by saletype do you mean request_type?

Comment: just corrected that. it should be saletype.

Comment: and you still not getting the correct output?

Comment: nope. you can try replicating error if you'd like by putting in a <cfabort var="#session.house.main# abort="true" /> right before the cflocation.

Comment: I don't have access to my Cf server at the moment so I can't play around with your code. Personal preference, I avoid cfform. Straight up regular forms are way better imo

Comment: If you take away the cflocation tag and replace it with a cfdump of your session scope, do you see your hoped for values?  Not related to your question, but be careful about putting stuff like this into the session scope.  With modern browsers, values might change in a way you didn't anticipate.

Comment: It appears that the form is submitting to the same page it's on.  Then the values are copied to the session scope and there is a cflocation tag to page2.  If that's the case, why not simply post the form data to page2?

Comment: In addition to dumping your session scope, you should dump your form scope.  Make sure you include a test where you submit the form by putting your focus in the name box and pressing the enter key.  You might not have a form.submit variable.

Comment: Dan & Geo, I honestly don't know what happened but somehow it is working now. I dumped the session scope instead of location and it came up, intrigued....so I went through the rest of the form process with all the original code, checked some validations, and it came up on the 3rd page as it should have. Seriously odd. I will run some more tests on other browsers and see if I can replicate the error.